# Android TextView text updation on receiving data from Inputstream

Tags: android, textview, android-bluetooth

I am coding a client-server app to test communication between two Android Bluetooth devices. On my client, I am reading data from the inputstream object.
When I checked by printing on the logcat, the data is being read successfully. However when I try to set the data to a TextView, it is not displaying.

In the following code, packetsReceivedTV is the TextView object. I am getting correct output when I print 'result' on logcat, but the text is not setting in the TextView. Is it because I am setting the text in a while (listening) loop?

```
while(listening){
            bytesRead =instream.read(buffer);

            if(bytesRead!=-1){

                    String dataRead= new String(buffer,"UTF-8");

                    System.err.println("*************result : "+dataRead);
                    packetsReceivedTV.setText("Received : "+dataRead);
                    packetsReceivedTV.invalidate();
            }


        }
```

Even a call to invalidate() is not working.

**NOTE:** Occasionally when I kill the server process on one device, then the TextView on the client device updates correctly. But this does not happen always. Please help!

Comment: Are you sure that you're calling setText() on the main thread?

Comment: @AndrewOrobator: Yes I am calling it on main thread. But I am also listening on the main thread, which I see is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear which thread your code is called on, but you need to make sure these two operations are happening on **different** threads:

- The stream polling needs to be done on a background thread. If you are not doing this, then you are not seeing text because the thread blocking on `read()` keeps the main thread from updating the UI elements.
- The `setText()` method call must happen on the main (UI) thread. If you are not doing this, the text will also not display--and on some devices you will even see crashes.

I'll assume this code live in an activity (since you are trying to update UI elements). ***While this is not the best practice***, a simple example that demonstrates the concept follows:

```
Thread pollingThread = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        …
        //This code needs to be running on a background thread
        while(listening){
            bytesRead = instream.read(buffer);

            if(bytesRead != -1){

                String dataRead= new String(buffer,"UTF-8");

                System.err.println("*************result : "+dataRead);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //This code needs to be posted back to the main thread.
                        packetsReceivedTV.setText("Received : "+dataRead);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
};
//Start the listener thread
pollingThread.start();
```

This is really just meant to illustrate the basic point that the polling code ***must*** be in the background and the view code ***must*** be on the main thread.

> Even a call to invalidate() is not working.

`TextView` calls this internally when its contents change, so you calling it is redundant.

Comment: I think you have diagnosed the problem correctly - I am doing it all in the main thread. I have not understood how to use runOnUiThread() and how the code can be posted back to main thread. Sorry if it's a silly question but, I am somewhat new to this!